# Turn Off TPMS Warning - Nissan Pathfinder'19

Tags: tires, nissan, winter, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

I've just changed to winter tires on our '19 Pathfinder. In previous years I've just had the tires switched onto rims but this year I've used an older set of rims. Unfortunately, I was busy when my father-in-law came and grabbed the rims and tires and had a friend of his mount them. I didn't get a chance to talk to him about the TPMS so he could ask his friend if sensors were present and if they looked in good order.

So first drive and the TPMS warning pings and stays lit. Not a problem to dismiss and ignore, but it does mean that future warnings, such as snow obscuring the forward-facing radar, will be harder to see.

So is there a way to disable the TPMS in settings or by removing a fuse?

Comment: There's no real way (to my knowledge) to disable the TPMS (unless you reprogram the computer). Even if the winter rims have TPMS sensors in them, you still have to program the system to understand these are the sensors the system should be looking at.

Comment: TPMS was mandated for the USA market in 2008. Defeating tpms is against the law. However, you can search for a youtube video of a person using new/used tpms sensors in a sealed pvc tube with tire valve fitted on and pressurized to 40 psi, enabling his tpms to detect and extinguish the warning indicator. It remains an owner's responsibility to ensure tires are inflated to correct pressures.

Comment: It looks like I'm stuck with it until the spring then! Not mandated here in Canada but still built the same. @FDryer - I can definitely get my hands on used sensors (brother-in-law has a salvage yard) but not sure we'll be able to get our hands on a reprogramming set though.

Comment: Ok, here's the video; https://youtu.be/XRMoaVh8qsc  Apparently, no programming is needed as the tpms detects the four sensors under pressure, wherever he placed the pressurized unit (trunk?) while still having dead sensors in all four wheels.